# Short lattice vectors in the complement of a hyperplane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lattices

Suppose that $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a lattice and $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a hyperplane such that $H \cap \Lambda$ has rank $n - 1$. I would like to know an upper bound on the shortest vector of $\Lambda$ not in $H$, ideally something in terms of the discriminant of $\Lambda$ and the discriminant of $H \cap \Lambda$.

For the situation I have in mind, the discriminant of $H \cap \Lambda$ will be very large compared to the discriminant of $\Lambda$, so intuitively I would expect there to be a short element of $\Lambda$ not on $H$, but I do not know a good way to show this.

Comment: One can readily derive lower bounds, see for example Prop. 1.2.9 or theorem 2.1.3 of Martinet's *Perfect Lattices in Euclidean Space*. This is of course not what you want, but at least theorem 2.1.3 has an equality condition which may be useful for constructing a potential counterexample to what you want.